# scale axis subplots created with df.boxplot(by=)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[100,23,1],[112,13,1],[212,3,2],[222,2,2]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I plot the boxplot using groupby

```
axes = df.boxplot(by='C', return_type='axes')
```

The problem is that I would like to scale the axis of my subplots in order to center the boxplots..

I tried with

```
describe = df.groupby('C').describe()

idx1=0
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylim(describe[axes.index[idx1]]['min'].min(),describe[axes.index[idx1]]['max'].max())
    idx1 = idx1 +1
```

but no luck

Comment: You have two box plots per subplot, the look centered to me.  Can you show what you want with a pic?

Comment: column A is of the order of 100 while column B is of the order of 10... I would like to have separate y axes for each of the subplot... for column A something like [80 120] for column B something like [0 20]